# Integral with fourth, cube and square root

Tags: calculus, integration

We are seeking to evaluate this integral:

$$\mathrm{\int_{1}^{4}\left (\frac{1}{x^{2}+\sqrt{{3x\left ( x^{2}-9\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{x-5}} \right )}}-\sqrt[4]{5x+7}}+x^{3}-6x^{2}+5x-3  \right )dx}$$

I have been trying to solve for hours, but I still can't find the solutions. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Where does this messy integral come from?

Comment: It comes from my text book.

Comment: Really! Which one? I am rather curious...

Comment: An Italian text book for the university of 80s.

Comment: It's a very old book,so I think you can't find iit on Internet... But for the integral?

Comment: I am not able to evaluate that integral. Also old books have title and author. Why do you want to keep this secret?

Comment: The newest version is: "Esercitazioni di Analisi Matematica 1", Zanichelli, 2008.

Comment: @Matteo Authors please.

Comment: @Robert Z, Marco Bramanti

Comment: @Matteo Thanks. I have a copy of that book which is full of standard exercises, but I am not able to find the one you are proposing. Maybe I have the wrong edition. Anyway, it does not matter...